# JavaScript && Operator in If Statement

Tags: javascript, operators

I came across this line:

```
if((x = myFunction(y)) && x.length) {
  //do something
}
```

`x.length` expression means what in this situation? Does it mean as long as x.length != 0?

Comment: yup `x.length` has mean `x` not equal with `0`

Comment: @FadhlyPermata thank you

Comment: That depends on what `x` is. `x.length` could be anything, but usually it's a  numeric property given to arrays and array-like objects, but `length` could just as well be anything.

Comment: It is testing whether `x.length` is "truthy". If you can assume that `myFunction()` returns something that has a numeric `.length` property then yes, it is testing that that property is not `0`. (You would get an error if `myFunction()` returned `undefined` or `null`.)

Comment: @nnnnnn - if `myFunction` returns a falsy value, the right hand side of `&&` won't be checked, and it doesn't error out.

Comment: @adeneo - Oh. Duh. Of course.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes. 0 is a 'falsey' value so `if(x.length)` and `if(x.length != 0)` will do the same thing

Answer (score 0):

if (x.length) can mean either of the following to the programmer.

```
if (x.length != 0) 
if (x.length != null) 
if (x.length != false)
```

I would imagine, for the interpreter all of it would be

```
if (x.length != 0)
```

Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: x.length could also be undefined - and would evaluate as falsey

Comment: "Please correct me if I am wrong." --- the standard declares that the `ToBoolean` is invoked on the expression result that is defined as http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-toboolean So it's slightly different to just `!= 0`

Comment: Thanks @user2182349. Forgot that!